# Raspberry 3 Wifi issues

Tags: wireless, reboot, raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate

Everytime I boot up my Raspberry 3 with Ubuntu MATE the Wifi is not enabled. If I do a reboot the Wifi is up and working perfectly. But I dont want to do a reboot everytime I use my Raspberry.

I am not able to activate it manually.  Also, if I try `ifconfig` the `wlan0`is not displayed.

Any ideas why it is like that?

Comment: What happens when you run the command "sudo ifconfig wlan0 up" in terminal (when your WiFi is down)?

Comment: Does the wifi adapter show up in the output of `sudo ifconfig -a`?  Does Ubuntu MATE network manager show the wifi card?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I did rpi-update what solved my problem. But thank you anyway!